# Navigation div outside of document flow, and I have no idea why

Tags: html, css, position

It's probably easier to start by showing what's happening.  The black box/div that's overlaying the page's body text is my site's main navigation (nav text is a light blue, so it may be hard to see).  It's *supposed* to be to the left of the feather image in the header (without the border).  Instead it's outside of the normal document flow:

[image]

And where it *should* be:

[image]

Here's my twig template:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Adi Rule, young adult author, author, NH, New Hampshire" />
        <meta name="description" content="Official homesite of Adi Rule, young adult author" />
        <title>{% block title %}Adi Rule{% endblock %}</title>
        {% stylesheets 'bundles/majorproductionsadisite/css/*.css' filter='cssrewrite' %}
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" type="text/css" />
        {% endstylesheets %}
        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="layout">
        <div id="header">
                <img src="{{ asset('bundles/majorproductionsadisite/images/adi-gradient-logo.jpg') }}" alt="Adi Rule" />
                <div id="nav">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="{{ path('_bio') }}">Bio</a></li> |
                        <li><a href="{{ path('_books') }}">Books</a></li> |
                        <li><a href="{{ path('_blog') }}">What's New</a></li> |
                        <li><a href="{{ path('_contact') }}">Contact</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="content">
                {% block content %}{% endblock %}
            </div>
            <hr />
            <div id="footer">
                Website designed and created by Major Productions LLC
            </div>
        </div>
        {% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

And the content template for that page (other pages haven't been constructed yet):

```
{% extends "::base.html.twig" %}

{% block content %}
<div class="book">
Music flows in Sing Da Navelli's blood. When she enrolls at a prestigious conservatory, her first opera audition is for the role of her dreams.
But this leading role is the last Sing's mother ever sang, before her controversial career, and her life, were cut tragically short.
As Sing struggles to escape her mother's shadow and prove her own worth, she is drawn to the conservatory's icy forest, a place steeped in history, magic, and danger.
She soon realizes there is more to her new school than the artistry and politics of classical music.
With the help of a dark-eyed apprentice who has secrets of his own, Sing must unravel the story of the conservatory's dark forest and the strange creature who lives there -- and find her own voice.
</div>

<div class="book">
<p>Papa says I’m a good girl, and he’s right. I don’t do anything bad. I’ve never stolen a piece of cake or killed a beetle. I’ve never wished harm on anyone, not even the priests who would damn me to Eternal Drowning. Not even the people who burned our house to the ground the night my mother died.</p>
<p>It’s a safety precaution. I can feel wickedness smoldering in my chest, balled up, writhing. Like the boiling water they pump out of the lake, solid lead pressing it on all sides until it sloshes and frenzies itself into steam, still trapped. I feel like if I did one small evil thing, I wouldn’t be able to stop myself until I’d laid waste to the world.</p>
<p>Papa says I’m a good girl, and he’s right.<br />
For now.</p>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

My confusion stems from my CSS.  I'm not using anything that jumps out at me that would suggest the nav div should be outside of the document flow.  Regardless, I'm not sure of the best way to position the navigation anyway.

My CSS:

```
@font-face{
    font-family: 'Pigeon';
    src: url('../fonts/pigeon-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/pigeon-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('../fonts/pigeon-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/pigeon-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('../fonts/pigeon-webfont.svg#webfont') format('svg');
}

#layout {
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    background-color: /* #7797a7; */ #7799aa;
    height: 121px;
    font-family: 'Pigeon', Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 2.25em;
}

#nav {
    color: #d2e6f0;
    width: 500px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

#nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}

#nav ul li a {
    color: #d2e6f0;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 110px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#nav ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #3981a6;
}

#content {
    margin: 40px auto;
    width: 600px;
}

hr {
    color: #a5cce0;
    background-color: #a5cce0;
}

#footer {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Any positioning help would be much appreciated.

Comment: could you post the link? it's more easy check with inspect element or firebug than read all that code

Comment: Link to what?  The site isn't live.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's pretty much the extent of my code.  I'm using normalize.css as my reset, and the content is just two `<div class="book"></div>` which I haven't styled yet.  There's literally nothing else.

Comment: i cant find .book in the html...we need to see the html...

Comment: Added the book content, not that it's at all relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is too much of a troubleshooting one, but I guess the feather image is pushing it down. Try positioning the image absolutely.

Comment: or alternatively, remove the <img> and style it with background-image.

Comment: Since the header is 121px high, I guess that would cause the feather to disappear below that height.

Comment: @afEkenholm That's correct.  It doesn't help that I'm both incredibly rusty at CSS, and never great to begin with.

Comment: Absolute positioning worked after I set the header's positioning to `relative` to set the context.  From there, it was just a matter of nudging things into the right place.